# Смогу ли я снова использовать Git, если перенесу папку с репозиторием в другое место?

Tags: git, github

Есть директория с проектом, где инициализирован git. Смогу ли я продолжить им пользоваться *(использовать push и pull)*, если перенесу директорию с проектом в другое место, при этом так же перенеся папку `.git`?

Comment: разумеется. . . .

Comment: Папка `.git` обычно лежит внутри папки с проектом, так что если переносить всё скопом, то никаких проблем нет.

Answer (score 1):

Репозиторий определяется подпапкой .git (или специальным файлом .git) в корне репозитория. Где именно находится папка репозитория, git не интересует.

Так что ответ: "да, сможете". Главное не делать это в процессе выполнения каких-нибудь длительных команд типа push, pull, gc и подобного.